Why is my layout not scrolling despite implementing Scrollview in android?
I have a layout file of a fragment in which i am trying to implement scrollview in it. I have made Scrollview as a parent view but still it doesn't scoll up and down. Below is the code of my layout file .
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lime_green">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewAvatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageAvatar"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAvatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:text="@string/select_your_avatar"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardViewAvatar"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewNotify">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/notification"
                android:id="@+id/imageNotify" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNotify"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/notifications" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardviewNotify"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewProgress">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/progresstrack"
                android:id="@+id/imageProgress" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textProgress"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:text="@string/progress_track" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardviewProgress"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewShare">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sharelinks1"
                android:id="@+id/imageShare" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textshare"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:text="Share" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardviewShare"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewSupport">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/support1"
                android:id="@+id/imageSupport" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textSupport"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:text="Help Desk" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardviewSupport"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewFeature">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/featurerequest"
                android:id="@+id/imageFeature" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFeature"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:text="@string/feature_request" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardviewFeature"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewAbout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/aboutapp"
                android:id="@+id/imageAbout" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAboutApp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:text="About" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardviewAbout"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewDelete">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/deletedata"
                android:id="@+id/imageDelete" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDeleteData"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card"
                android:text="Delete Data" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

Below is the fragment code
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R
import com.example.visuallithuanian.adapter.SpinnerAdapter
import com.example.visuallithuanian.databinding.FragmentSettingsBinding
import com.example.visuallithuanian.ui.activities.FirstScreen
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView


class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding:FragmentSettingsBinding
lateinit var bottomNav: BottomNavigationView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)


    // Taking the BottomNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
    bottomNav = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
    bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE



    return binding.root
}
}

I am trying to implement Scrolling feature on my screen but my screen is not getting scrolling. I have made Scrollview as my parent view but still not success.

I tried running your XML code and it is working

It's not working in mine, I don't know why.

The height of the inner interface must exceed the height of the screen at that time. then the scrollview will work.
Try opening the app on a smaller screen

Can you help me with the code ? Like can you show what exact changes you should make ?

It's not a code tutorial. You just need to run your project on a screen with high and low pitch. you will see the scrollview working

My scrollview is working on smaller devices and not on medium ones.

Then it's not an error. Only when the views overflow off the screen will the scrollView become active.
The purpose of scrollView is so that you can manipulate all views. If your view is all displayed on the screen, scrollView does not need to be active.
You know what I mean, if not, you can take a screenshot of your screen on 2 devices (small, medium) and post it here. I will help you clarify

Yes, I understood your point now. I checked on various devices and screens and your point is right. Thank you

Can you give me a vote if you find it useful? Thank you. @Freya19

Yes, I did thank you :) are you on Github?
